# Two ways of calculating the flux of a vector field not consistent

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, surfaces, vector-fields

I want to compute the flux of $F(x,y,z)=(xy)\pmb{i}+(yz)\pmb{j}+(zx)\pmb{k}$ across the surface $S$ given by the paraboloid $z=9-x^2-y^2$ over $[-1,1]\times[-1,1]$.

Ok, so I will compute $flux(F)=\int\int_S F\cdot N\;dS$.

Taking $f(x,y)=(x,y,9-x^2-y^2)$, then
$$N={1\over\sqrt{1+4x^2+4y^2}} \begin{bmatrix} 2x \\ 2y \\ 1\end{bmatrix},$$
so
$$N\cdot F dS={1\over\sqrt{1+4x^2+4y^2}} \begin{bmatrix} 2x \\ 2y \\ 1\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix} xy \\ yz \\ zx\end{bmatrix}\sqrt{1+4x^2+4y^2}\;dA.$$

Thus,
\begin{align}
flux(F)&=\int\int_S F\cdot N\;dS=\int\int 2x^2y+2y^2z+zx\;dA\\
&=\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-1}^{1}2x^2y+2y^2(9-x^2-y^2)+(9-x^2-y^2)x\;dy\;dx\\
&={968\over 45}.
\end{align}

Right, but there is another to compute this using the divergence theorem. This is
$$flux(F)=\int\int_S F\cdot N\;dS=\int\int\int_E\;div(F)\;dV.$$
We have that $div(F)=x+y+z$, so that
\begin{align}
flux(F)&=\int\int\int_E x+y+z\;dV=\\
&=\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-1}^{1}x(9-x^2-y^2)+y(9-x^2-y^2)+{1\over 2}(9-x^2-y^2)^2\;dx\;dy\\
&={6266\over 45}.
\end{align}

As you see, the results obtained with each method don't agree. I double-checked the computations by hand and with Mathematica, so I assume there must be a conceptual mistake or something like this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You may not use the divergence theory because $S$ is not the boundary of a solid.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Oh, yes, of course! The paraboloid is infinite and there is no cut with a plane or something like that so we could apply the theorem in this case... Well spotted, thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome, dear Edu.